# Overriding bash PS1 not working

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to update my bash/terminal prompt, but exporting PS1 doesn't do anything.

```
COMPUTER:~ me$ echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$
COMPUTER:~ me$ export PS1="foo"
COMPUTER:~ me$ echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$
```

I'm on mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, Terminal 2.5.3.  I've tried placing this in my .bash_profile as well, but nothing seems to override the default PS1.  What might be preventing this?

Comment: Thanks! I set my PROMPT_COMMAND for virtual environments in my .bash_profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to 4ae1e1, I checked my `PROMPT_COMMAND` was set in my .bash_profile for virtual environments.

I changed

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "${VIRTUAL_ENV:+[$Yellow`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`$Color_Off]\n}" "\h:\W \u\ \\\$ " "[%s]\n"'`
```

to

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "${VIRTUAL_ENV:+[$Yellow`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`$Color_Off]\n}" "\w \\\$ " "[%s]\n"'`
```

(or more clearly the part `"\h:\W \u\ \\\$ "` to `"\w \\\$ "`)